# How to capture unique object from webcam?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, darknet, darkflow

I have trained my model for single class, i want to capture(Count) the same object from webcam once, means if same object detecting in frame then it should capture as one until it leave the frame.

In my case it captures the same object multiple times(means it saves the multiple images for same object) but i want single image for single object.

Anyone Can tell me please how can we do this in Darknet/Darkflow using python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is good question, interesting.